# Insert new line after every record in python and comma between elements of record

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my code for parsing a html file. After parsing the table I need to store each record in a file and I need a line break after every record and every element in a record should be separated by a comma. I managed to get the line break but not the comma.

This is my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os

OUTFILE = os.path.join('company', 'a', 'viewids')

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/company/a/searches/a"))
rows = soup.findAll("table",{"id":"cos"})
records = []
for tr in rows:
   cols = tr.findAll('td')
   for td in cols:
    record = td.contents[0]
    records.append(record+'\n')
open(OUTFILE, 'w').writelines(records)
```

This is the record:

```
A CONSULTING TEAM INC 1040792 7380

A J&J PHARMA CORP 1140452 9995

My output is:

A CONSULTING TEAM INC

1040792

7380

A J&J PHARMA CORP

1140452

9995
```

Comment: What does `record` look like?

Comment: I have updated it in my question

Comment: Are rows of the table records? If yes, it is quite confusing that you assign individual cells into a variable named `record`. Look for `tr` elements if you want rows.

Comment: No. The rows have 3 columns. I want comma between the column values and line break between each row.

Comment: OP's explicit requirements (and his probable implicit requirements) make this a job for ... `import csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rows = soup.findAll("table",{"id":"cos"})[0].findAll('tr')
records = []
for tr in rows:
  cols = tr.findAll('td')
  record = ''
  for td in cols:
    if record != '': record = record + ', '
    record = record + td.contents[0]
  records.append(record + "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now the elements of the record are comma separated but there is no line break after each record.

Comment: Still it is comma separated.

Comment: Don't they need to be comma-separated? (My edit was to add line breaks.)

Comment: Are 'A CONSULTING TEAM INC' and 'A J&J PHARMA CORP' in different `tr`s?

Comment: Just noticed that `rows` was not actually rows. Added some corrected code above the loop.

Comment: Yes it works now. However it adds a new line to the beginning of the file. How should I remove it?

Comment: Maybe there is a header `<tr>` at the top of table. Try to replace the last line with: `if record != '': records.append(record + "\n")`

Answer (score 1):

### Comma-separated values

The file format you're describing is simply the CSV format.
Take a tour on Wikipedia and search "Comma-separated values".

With Python, you can use the `csv` package.
Go to http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html to see the documentation.

The simplest way of writing a CSV file is as follow:

```
import csv

records = [[1951, 'Superman and the Mole Men', 'DC Comics', 'Lee Sholem'],
           [1966, 'Batman', 'DC Comics', 'Leslie H. Martinson'],
           [2002, 'Spider-Man', 'Marvel Comics', 'Sam Raimi'],
           [2008, 'Iron Man', 'Marvel Comics', 'Jon Favreau']]

with open('heros.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerows(records)
```

The result is a classic CSV file:

```
1951,Superman and the Mole Men,DC Comics,Lee Sholem
1966,Batman,DC Comics,Leslie H. Martinson
2002,Spider-Man,Marvel Comics,Sam Raimi
2008,Iron Man,Marvel Comics,Jon Favreau
```

Of course, you can add the header:

```
with open('heros.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerows([['Year', 'Film', 'Publisher', 'Director']])
    writer.writerows(records)
```

**note:** the header is a list of list (look at the double brackets)

The result is the following CSV file:

```
Year,Film,Publisher,Director
1951,Superman and the Mole Men,DC Comics,Lee Sholem
1966,Batman,DC Comics,Leslie H. Martinson
2002,Spider-Man,Marvel Comics,Sam Raimi
2008,Iron Man,Marvel Comics,Jon Favreau
```

### Reading an HTML table

First of all, use a `with` statement to open a file in secured manner.

For example, to read a text file, process as follow:

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as fp:
    content = fp.read()
```

That way, if an error occurs during reading, the file will be automatically
closed at the end of the `with` statement, before the exception is raised.
Nothing is left opened!

To read an HTML table with `BeautifulSoup` (which I don't know), you can do:

```
with open("/company/a/searches/a") as html_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)
    rows = soup.findAll("table", {"id": "cos"})
    records = []
    for tr in rows:
        record = []
        cols = tr.findAll('td')
        for td in cols:
            record.append(td.contents[0])
        records.append(record)
```

The `records` list will contains the entire table.
You can then write it into a CSV file.

### Handling UNICODE values

HTML doesn't contains ASCII strings but UNICODE string and I suppose that
`td.contents[0]` will return an `unicode` instance.

But, the `csv` module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode.
So, you will need to write `unicode` string using `UTF-8` encoding during your
CSV serialization. I recommend you to look at the `unicode_csv_reader()` function
in the example: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples.